# Pass JSON data (by using Ajax ) to table in View Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am new to Laravel and trying to self learn the same for inhouse project.

Trying to pass json data to table for showing the data in the same. Data received in json is ok but not able to put the same in Table

Controller:

```
public function getmilkrecordforbid(Request $req) 
                {
                    $bidformilk = $req->bidformilkrecord;
            
                    $bmilkrecord    = buffalomilkrecord::where('buffaloID', '=', $bidformilk)- 
                    >get(); 
     
                   return ($bmilkrecord);
                }
```

web.php

```
       Route::post('/getmilkrecordforbid'[BuffalodataController::class,'getmilkrecordforbid'])
```

ajax file

```
              $('#selectid').on('change', function() {

                var bidformilkrecord = $('#selectid').val(); 

                    $.ajax({  
                        url         :   '/getmilkrecordforbid', 
                        dataType    :   "json",
                        method      :   "POST",
                        data        :   {'bidformilkrecord': bidformilkrecord, "_token":"{{ 
                                        csrf_token()}}"},

                    success: function(data){ 
                        
                        console.log(data)
                        console.log(data.length)
                    },  
                });
            });
```

console.log

```
       (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]0: {id: 5, buffaloID: 'Buffalo-02', date: '2020-12-15', milkmorning: '5.00', milkevening: '6.00', …}1: {id: 6, buffaloID: 'Buffalo-02', date: '2020-12-16', milkmorning: '5.00', milkevening: '5.00', …}2: {id: 7, buffaloID: 'Buffalo-02', date: '2020-12-17', milkmorning: '5.00', milkevening: '5.00', …}3: {id: 8, buffaloID: 'Buffalo-02', date: '2020-12-18', milkmorning: '5.00', milkevening: '5.00', …}length: 4[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Table html

```
       <table id="milksummery" class="table table-bordered table-hover table" 
             style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Morning Milk</th>
                    th>Evening Milk</th>
                    <th>Total Milk</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                                                
            </tbody>

    </table>
```

Your guidance will really help me.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to manipulate the DOM on the success event. We are getting the first tbody element and adding more elements to it.

Here it is your code with the updated DOM.

```
$('#selectid').on('change', function() {

        var bidformilkrecord = $('#selectid').val(); 

            $.ajax({  
                url         :   '/getmilkrecordforbid', 
                dataType    :   "json",
                method      :   "POST",
                data        :   {
                    'bidformilkrecord': bidformilkrecord,
                    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                },
            success: function(data){ 
                console.log(data)
                console.log(data.length)

                let tbody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

                for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    let milkSummeryRow = tbody.insertRow();
                    let dateCell = milkSummeryRow.insertCell();
                    let dateText = document.createTextNode(data[i]['date']);
                    dateCell.appendChild(dateText);
                    
                    let milkMorningCell = milkSummeryRow.insertCell();
                    let milkMorningText = document.createTextNode(data[i]['milkmorning']);
                    milkMorningCell.appendChild(milkMorningText);

                    let milkEveningCell = milkSummeryRow.insertCell();
                    let milkEveningText = document.createTextNode(data[i]['milkevening']);
                    milkEveningCell.appendChild(milkEveningText);

                    let milkTotalCell = milkSummeryRow.insertCell();
                    let milkTotalText = document.createTextNode(parseFloat(data[i]['milkmorning']) + parseFloat(data[i]['milkevening']));
                    milkTotalCell.appendChild(milkTotalText);
                }

            },  
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hello... Thanks for Quick reply and its works but there 2 problem i am facing...   1. I have 2 table in the page and its showing the data on  the 1st table which i am expecting on 2nd table. I check the id for table and 1st table id is different.. 2. table data get clear when i refresh the page. Can u suggest the solution for the same.

Comment: Thank u ......Did some modification and now table is showing the data.                           
But now i am facing a problem. when i select the id say Buffalo-01, data is showing - (3 Row) then again i select Buffalo-02.. table shows data for both id ( say 3+3), I need to refresh the datatable so that after selecting id for next time previous data should be removed and new data for selected id should be shown. Hope you understand the prob..... Can help me on the same...Thanks